# Difference between gridded data and station data

Tags: grads

I just started practicing GrADS tutorial. 
and I'm stuck at the first page which was about '**gridded data**' and '**station data**'

What is the **difference between gridded data and station data?**
Furthermore, **when do we use** gridded or station data?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the topic but [this link](http://www.wishingwork.com/grads/gridded-station-data.html) comes among the first results from google search. It seems to me it answers your quesiton

Answer (score 0):

Station data contains observations at different "stations." That could be readings from ASOS or other platforms. Gridded data is more like model output. You have a grid on which the numerical model is ran, with this you have a data value at every grid point, both horizontally and vertically.

As for usage, it depends what you are trying to visualize/analyze.

Let me know if you have other questions, I have a lot of experience with GrADS and atmospheric science gridded data.